# How to show only the 'plot' values (at the title) and not the plot drawings on the chart?

Tags: pine-script

**SMA lines (plot drawings) are not to be drawn/shown** but plot values are to be displayed at the title (by default this is shown).

Code for reference:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Moving Average", shorttitle="SMA", overlay=true, resolution="")
len = input(20, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = sma(src, len)
plot(out, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making the plot color fully transparent.

`plot(out, color = color.rgb(red = 255, green = 0, blue = 0, transp = 100))`

This will show the `out` value in the title, in the correct color, but without the transparency value.